# Reproducing the following base graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'd like to reproduce the following base graph with ggplot2.
[image]

Following is the *R* code to produce this graph.

```
set.seed(12345)
Data <- matrix(data = rnorm(n = 30, mean = 0, sd = 1), nrow = 6, ncol = 5)
dimnames(Data) <- list(paste("G", 1:nrow(Data), sep = ""), paste("E", 1:ncol(Data), sep     = ""))
SVD <- svd(Data)
D <- diag(SVD$d[1:min(dim(Data))])
G <- SVD$u%*%sqrt(D)
E <- SVD$v%*%sqrt(D)

dimnames(G) <- list(rownames(Data))
dimnames(E) <- list(colnames(Data))

SVD.Values <- SVD$d
PC.No <- c(1:length(SVD.Values))
PC.SS <- SVD.Values^2
PC.Percent.SS <- PC.SS/sum(PC.SS)*100


library(grDevices)
con.hull.pos <- chull(G)
con.hull <- rbind(G[con.hull.pos, ], G[con.hull.pos[1], ])

getPerpPoints <- function(mat) {
x <- mat[,1]
y <- mat[,2]
out <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
if(diff(x) == 0) {
xnew <- x[1]
  }
  else {
xnew <- (diff(y) / diff(x)) * x[1] - y[1]
xnew <- xnew / (diff(y) / diff(x) + diff(x) / diff(y))
  }
  ynew <- -(diff(x) / diff(y)) * xnew
  out[2,] <- c(xnew, ynew)
  return(out = out)
}

r <- 0.08
plot(x = G[ ,1], y = G[ ,2], type = "p", xlim = range(c(E[,1], G[,1])) + range(c(E[,1],     G[,1])) * r,
    ylim = range(c(E[,2], G[,2])) + range(c(E[,2], G[,2])) * r,
    xlab = paste(paste("PC1 (", round(PC.Percent.SS[1], 1), sep = ""), "%)", sep = ""),
    ylab = paste(paste("PC2 (", round(PC.Percent.SS[2], 1), sep = ""), "%)", sep = ""),
    xaxs = "r", yaxs = "r",
    pch = 19, cex = 1, panel.first = grid(col="gray", lty="dotted"),
    main = "")
text(x = G[,1], y = G[,2], labels = row.names(G), pos = 1, col = "blue")
points(x = E[,1], y = E[,2], type = "n", col = "blue", lwd = 5)
text(x = E[,1], y = E[,2], labels = row.names(E), pos = 1, col = "red") #c(-0.2, 0.4)
abline(h = 0, v = 0, lty = 2.5, col = "green", lwd = 2)
s <- seq(length(E[, 1]))
arrows(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, x1 = E[, 1][s], y1 = E[, 2][s], col = "brown", lwd = 1.8, length     = 0.1, code = 2)
lines(con.hull)
for(i in 1:(nrow(con.hull)-1)) {
  lines(getPerpPoints(con.hull[i:(i+1),]), lty =  "solid")
}
```

I used the following code to make this graph with ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
G <- as.data.frame(G)
colnames(G) <- c(paste("PC", 1:min(dim(Data)), sep = ""))
G$ID <- "G"
G$Name <- rownames(G)
E <- as.data.frame(E)
colnames(E) <- c(paste("PC", 1:min(dim(Data)), sep = ""))
E$ID <- "E"
E$Name <- rownames(E)

GE <- rbind(G[, c("PC1", "PC2", "ID", "Name")], E[, c("PC1", "PC2", "ID", "Name")])

p <- qplot(x = PC1, y = PC2, data = GE, colour = ID, label = Name, geom = "text", size     = 1,
           xlab = paste(paste("PC1 (", round(PC.Percent.SS[1], 1), sep = ""), "%)", sep     = ""),
           ylab = paste(paste("PC2 (", round(PC.Percent.SS[2], 1), sep = ""), "%)", sep     = ""),
           main = "") + opts(legend.position = "none")
p <- p + geom_hline(aes(0), size=.2) + geom_vline(aes(0), size=.2)
p <- p + geom_segment(data = E, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2), arrow =     arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm")), alpha = 1, color = "red")
p
```

and my attempted graph is

[image]

Now I have difficulty to map the convex hull on this graph and in reducing the size of the arrows.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(data=as.data.frame(G), aes(V1, V2)) +
            geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="green", linetype=2, size=1) +
            geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="green", linetype=2, size=1) +
            geom_point() +
            geom_text(aes(label=row.names(G)), vjust=1.25, colour="blue") +
            geom_path(data=as.data.frame(con.hull), aes(V1, V2)) +
            geom_segment(data=as.data.frame(E),
                         aes(xend=V1, yend=V2), x=0, y=0,
                         colour="brown", arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.5 ,"cm"))) +
            geom_text(data=as.data.frame(E), aes(label=row.names(E)),
                      vjust=1.35, colour="red") +
            labs(list(x=sprintf("PC1 (%.1f%%)", PC.Percent.SS[1]),
                      y=sprintf("PC2 (%.1f%%)", PC.Percent.SS[2]))) +
            xlim(range(c(E[,1], G[,1]))*(1+r)) +
            ylim(range(c(E[,2], G[,2]))*(1+r))

tmp <- t(sapply(1:(nrow(con.hull)-1),
         function(i) getPerpPoints(con.hull[i:(i+1),])[2, ]))
p <- p + geom_segment(data=as.data.frame(tmp),
                      aes(xend=V1, yend=V2), x=0, y=0)    

print(p)
```

[image: ggplot2 example]

Comment: Thanks for nice attempt. I'd appreciate if you also do how to add perpendiculars to the sides of convex hull. Thanks

Comment: I'd be grateful if you help me to write a function from this code. I tried it but I'm facing some problems http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14603/ggplot2-in-function-or-s4   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140859/ggplot2-produces-error-when-used-in-function-or-s4. Thanks a lot.