# ggplot2 produces error when used in function or S4

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tough time with ggplot2 when used in function or S4. Here is my code without function:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library(nlme)
data(Oats)
Data <- Oats

Data$Env <- factor(Data$Block)
Data$Gen  <- factor(Data$Variety)

Data$Gen <- factor(Data$Gen)
Data$Env <- factor(Data$Env)
Gen.No <- length(levels(Data$Gen))
Env.No <- length(levels(Data$Env))
Min.G.E <- min(Gen.No, Env.No)

GGE.ANOVA <- aov(yield ~ Env + Env:Gen, data = Data)
GGE.Effs <- model.tables(GGE.ANOVA, type = "effects", cterms = "Env:Gen")$tables$"Env:Gen"
SVD <- svd(GGE.Effs)
D <- diag(SVD$d[1:Min.G.E])
E <- SVD$u%*%sqrt(D)
G <- SVD$v%*%sqrt(D)
Ecolnumb <- c(1:Min.G.E)
Ecolnames <- paste("PC", Ecolnumb, sep="")
dimnames(E) <- list(levels(Data$Env), Ecolnames)
dimnames(G) <- list(levels(Data$Gen), Ecolnames)
SVD.Values <- SVD$d
PC.No <- c(1:length(SVD.Values))
PC.SS <- SVD.Values^2
PC.Percent.SS <- PC.SS/sum(PC.SS)*100

library(grDevices)
con.hull.pos <- chull(G)
con.hull <- rbind(G[con.hull.pos, ], G[con.hull.pos[1], ])

getPerpPoints <- function(mat) {
x <- mat[,1]
y <- mat[,2]
out <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
if(diff(x) == 0) {
xnew <- x[1]
  }
  else {
xnew <- (diff(y) / diff(x)) * x[1] - y[1]
xnew <- xnew / (diff(y) / diff(x) + diff(x) / diff(y))
  }
  ynew <- -(diff(x) / diff(y)) * xnew
  out[2,] <- c(xnew, ynew)
  return(out = out)
    }
tmp <- t(sapply(1:(nrow(con.hull)-1),
     function(i) getPerpPoints(con.hull[i:(i+1),])[2, ]))
tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)


library(ggplot2)
r <- 0.08
p <- ggplot(data = as.data.frame(G), aes(PC1, PC2)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = row.names(G)), size = 3, vjust = 1.25, colour = "black")
p <- p + geom_path(data = as.data.frame(con.hull), aes(PC1, PC2))
p <- p + geom_segment(data = as.data.frame(E), aes(xend = PC1, yend = PC2), x = 0, y = 0,
                  colour = "black", arrow = arrow(angle = 25, length = unit(0.25, "cm")))
p <- p + geom_text(data = as.data.frame(E), aes(label = row.names(E)),
               size = 3, vjust = 1.35, colour = "black")
p <- p + labs(list(x = sprintf("PC1 (%.1f%%)", PC.Percent.SS[1]),
               y = sprintf("PC2 (%.1f%%)", PC.Percent.SS[2])))
p <- p  + opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.54, vjust = 0))
p <- p  + opts(axis.title.y = theme_text(size = 10, angle = 90,  vjust = 0.25))
p <- p + xlim(range(c(E[ ,1], G[ ,1])) + range(c(E[ ,1], G[ ,1]))*r)
p <- p + ylim(range(c(E[ ,2], G[ ,2])) + range(c(E[ ,2], G[ ,2]))*r)
p <- p + geom_segment(data = as.data.frame(tmp), aes(xend = tmp$V1, yend = tmp$V2), x = 0, y = 0)
print(p)
```

and the output is 
[image]

But when I use the same code in the following function, I got error

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
PlotGGE <- function(Response, Env, Gen, Data) {

Data$Env <- factor(Data$Env)
Data$Gen  <- factor(Data$Gen)
Gen.No <- length(levels(Data$Gen))
Env.No <- length(levels(Data$Env))
Min.G.E <- min(Gen.No, Env.No)

GGE.ANOVA <- aov(yield ~ Env + Env:Gen, data = Data)
GGE.Effs <- model.tables(GGE.ANOVA, type = "effects", cterms = "Env:Gen")$tables$"Env:Gen"
SVD <- svd(GGE.Effs)
D <- diag(SVD$d[1:Min.G.E])
E <- SVD$u%*%sqrt(D)
G <- SVD$v%*%sqrt(D)
Ecolnumb <- c(1:Min.G.E)
Ecolnames <- paste("PC", Ecolnumb, sep="")
dimnames(E) <- list(levels(Data$Env), Ecolnames)
dimnames(G) <- list(levels(Data$Gen), Ecolnames)
SVD.Values <- SVD$d
PC.No <- c(1:length(SVD.Values))
PC.SS <- SVD.Values^2
PC.Percent.SS <- PC.SS/sum(PC.SS)*100

library(grDevices)
con.hull.pos <- chull(G)
con.hull <- rbind(G[con.hull.pos, ], G[con.hull.pos[1], ])

getPerpPoints <- function(mat) {
x <- mat[,1]
y <- mat[,2]
out <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
if(diff(x) == 0) {
xnew <- x[1]
  }
  else {
xnew <- (diff(y) / diff(x)) * x[1] - y[1]
xnew <- xnew / (diff(y) / diff(x) + diff(x) / diff(y))
  }
  ynew <- -(diff(x) / diff(y)) * xnew
  out[2,] <- c(xnew, ynew)
  return(out = out)
    }
tmp <- t(sapply(1:(nrow(con.hull)-1),
     function(i) getPerpPoints(con.hull[i:(i+1),])[2, ]))
tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)


library(ggplot2)
r <- 0.08
p <- ggplot(data = as.data.frame(G), aes(PC1, PC2)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = row.names(G)), size = 3, vjust = 1.25, colour = "black")
p <- p + geom_path(data = as.data.frame(con.hull), aes(PC1, PC2))
p <- p + geom_segment(data = as.data.frame(E), aes(xend = PC1, yend = PC2), x = 0, y = 0,
                  colour = "black", arrow = arrow(angle = 25, length = unit(0.25, "cm")))
p <- p + geom_text(data = as.data.frame(E), aes(label = row.names(E)),
               size = 3, vjust = 1.35, colour = "black")
p <- p + labs(list(x = sprintf("PC1 (%.1f%%)", PC.Percent.SS[1]),
               y = sprintf("PC2 (%.1f%%)", PC.Percent.SS[2])))
p <- p  + opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.54, vjust = 0))
p <- p  + opts(axis.title.y = theme_text(size = 10, angle = 90,  vjust = 0.25))
p <- p + xlim(range(c(E[ ,1], G[ ,1])) + range(c(E[ ,1], G[ ,1]))*r)
p <- p + ylim(range(c(E[ ,2], G[ ,2])) + range(c(E[ ,2], G[ ,2]))*r)
p <- p + geom_segment(data = as.data.frame(tmp), aes(xend = tmp$V1, yend = tmp$V2), x = 0, y = 0)
print(p)
}

library(nlme)
data(Oats)
```

**EDIT**

```
Oats$Env <- factor(Oats$Block)
Oats$Gen <- factor(Oats$Variety)
PlotGGE(Response = yield, Env = Env, Gen = Gen, Data = Oats)
```

The error is

```
Error in row.names(G) : object 'G' not found
```

Any help and/or comments will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, your code is not the same in both instances.  The first line in your `PlotGGE` function is `Data$Env <- factor(Data$Env)`.  Since you pass `Oats` to your function, this is equivalent to `Oats$Env <- factor(Oats$Env)`.  Since `Oats` doesn't have an `Env` column, this causes your error.  This has nothing to do with `ggplot`.

Comment: i would not expect the very first line of your function to work as intended. Try `Data[[Env]]` instead, with `Env = "Block"`. More generally, try to debug smaller pieces at a time.

Comment: FYI: Cross Posted, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14603/ggplot2-in-function-or-s4

Comment: Sorry for cross posting. Next time I'll take care of this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `label` columns to the data frames. 
Also, note that you should never have a $ inside `aes`.

This should work:

```
G1 <- data.frame(G, label=rownames(G))
E1 <- data.frame(E, label=rownames(E))

library(ggplot2)
r <- 0.08
p <- ggplot(data=G1, aes(PC1, PC2)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label=label), size=3, vjust=1.25, colour="black")
p <- p + geom_path(data=as.data.frame(con.hull), aes(PC1, PC2))
p <- p + geom_segment(data=as.data.frame(E), aes(xend = PC1, yend=PC2),
                      x=0, y=0, colour="black",
                      arrow=arrow(angle=25, length=unit(0.25, "cm")))
p <- p + geom_text(data=E1, aes(label=label),
                   size=3, vjust=1.35, colour="black")
p <- p + labs(list(x=sprintf("PC1 (%.1f%%)", PC.Percent.SS[1]),
                   y=sprintf("PC2 (%.1f%%)", PC.Percent.SS[2])))
p <- p  + opts(axis.title.x=theme_text(size=10, hjust=0.54, vjust=0))
p <- p  + opts(axis.title.y=theme_text(size=10, angle=90, vjust=0.25))
p <- p + xlim(range(c(E[ ,1], G[ ,1])) + range(c(E[ ,1], G[ ,1]))*r)
p <- p + ylim(range(c(E[ ,2], G[ ,2])) + range(c(E[ ,2], G[ ,2]))*r)
p <- p + geom_segment(data=tmp, aes(xend=V1, yend=V2), x=0, y=0)
print(p)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have saved me. How smart are you?

Answer (score 3):

Your version in the function is missing the following two lines at the very beginning compared to the original version:

```
Data$Env <- factor(Data$Block)
Data$Gen  <- factor(Data$Variety)
```

Have you experimented with using `debug()` to step through functions to find the source of errors?

Comment: +1 for debug and I would also like to mention `?browser` (I find it more convenient).

Comment: @Joran: I've edited the code. Please have a look again. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 The corrected function runs fine for me, so there must be some other discrepancy between the code you're running and the code you posted. But now that you know about `debug()` you can easily find the problem yourself! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set as.data.frame(G) outside of your ggplot2 call if you want to be able to use rownames(G).

Set data=as.data.frame(G) in your call to geom_text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed your guidelines but have the same error. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you output the result of `str(G)`?

Comment: str(G)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ PC1: num  0.812 -4.796 3.983
 $ PC2: num  -3.58 1.29 2.29
 $ PC3: num  -3.95e-08 -3.95e-08 -3.95e-08

Comment: So it seems the call to as.data.frame(G) is redundanct in ggplot(...). Did you try moving `label = row.names(G)` into the 1st call to ggplot?

Comment: Yes I did and got the same error message. If I remove the three lines which have row.names, then the function works. I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = row.names(G)), size = 3, vjust = 1.25, colour = "black")
```

You're providing it with a layer, but no data to plot. Either move `label=` into your original call to ggplot or provide `geom_text()` with a `data=` argument