# ggplot2 does not appear to work when inside a function R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a bit new to R - I've been trying to wrap an R script as a function so I can call it from Rserve. Does anyone know why ggplot2 would not work inside a function yet works just fine outside of it?

```
png('polarity.png')
ggplot(sent_df, aes(x=polarity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=polarity)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdGy") +
  labs(x="polarity categories", y="number of conversatins") +
  opts(title = "Sentiment Analysis of Posts on Facebook\n(classification by polarity)",
       plot.title = theme_text(size=12))
dev.off()
```

This may have something to do with it [ggplot2 produces error when used in function or S4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140859/ggplot2-produces-error-when-used-in-function-or-s4) but I'm not getting an error that I can detect - I just get no output.

Comment: Dirk's answer should solve your problem, but additionally you should update your version of `ggplot2` (`opts` is deprecated), and it's usually nicer to use `ggsave()` for saving ggplots.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an R FAQ -- you need `print()` around it, or a `ggsave()` which is particular to ggplot2.

From the FAQ:

> 7.22 Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?
>
> The most likely reason is that you forgot to tell R to display the
>   graph. Lattice functions such as `xyplot()` create a graph object, but
>   do not display it (the same is true of ggplot2 graphics, and Trellis
>   graphics in S-Plus). The `print()` method for the graph object produces
>   the actual display. When you use these functions interactively at the
>   command line, the result is automatically printed, but in `source()` or
>   inside your own functions you will need an explicit `print()` statement.

Comment: `ggsave()` only saves-to-file, doesn't display.

Comment: `print(g)` may not render some objects.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458051/store-arrangegrob-to-object-does-not-create-printable-object which suggests `grid.draw()` for them.

Comment: But why is that not needed when I type into the console?