# store arrangeGrob to object, does not create printable object

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I want to *save*, but not print (for now), a bunch of `ggplot()`s into a grid (via `arrangeGrob()`, correct?), then print and retrieve them later.

This is a reboot of an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062766/store-output-from-gridextragrid-arrange-into-an-object).
Strangely, [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062766/store-output-from-gridextragrid-arrange-into-an-object) does not work, and I have no idea why.
I am using the exact same code.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
  p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=wt)) + geom_boxplot()
  library(gridExtra)
  y <- arrangeGrob(p1, p2)
  class(y)
  y
```

Strangely, that does *not* (as in the above answer) yield the grid of plots, but:

```
> class(y)
[1] "gtable" "grob"   "gDesc" 
> y
TableGrob (2 x 1) "arrange": 2 grobs
  z     cells    name           grob
1 1 (1-1,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
2 2 (2-2,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `gridExtra` package has been updated recently thereby changing how `arrangeGrob` works internally and what kind of object it returns (now a `gtable`).

You need to call `grid.draw`:

```
grid.draw(y)
```

[image: resulting plot]

**Edit:** do not use `plot()` as initially suggested; it will add a grey background, and is only meant to be used for debugging gtables.

Comment: an answer to this other question recommends to **use `grid.draw()`**, *not* `plot()`. I am confused. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463445/how-do-i-get-rid-of-random-background-grid-from-arrangegrob

Author of other answer appears to be package author ...

Comment: @maxheld actually this answer does not explain how to save the plot with `ggsave` later in your plot, does it? My problem is the saving, don't know how to change my code without download the development version from ggplot2

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the output from `grid.draw(x)` appears to be NULL in most cases. To get around this and work with ggsave, I have used `ggpubr::as_ggplot(x)`. This converts the gtable/grobArrange() into a class of `ggplot` which can then be worked with as usual. Additional technical note, I believe `as_ggplot()` builds on code from `cowplot`.

Comment: Is the `grid.draw` mentioned here `grid::grid.draw`? There seems to be no `grid.draw` in `gridExtra`. I opted for `gridExtra::grid.arrange` for a similar object.