# problems with arrangeGrob under R version 3.2.2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, grob

I 've updated my R version including all packages and the function arrangeGrob (Package gridExtra) has changed.

On my old version R version 3.1.3 I used it as the following to make corner labels:

**loading r packages**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

**example data**

```
a <- 1:20
b <- sample(a, 20)
c <- sample(b, 20)
d <- sample(c, 20)
```

**create a data frame**

```
mydata   <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
```

**create example plots**

```
myplot1  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point()
myplot2  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=b, y=c)) + geom_point()
myplot3  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=c, y=d)) + geom_point()
myplot4  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=d, y=a)) + geom_point()
```

**set corner labels**

```
 myplot1 <- arrangeGrob(myplot1, main = textGrob("A", x = unit(0, "npc")
     , y   = unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
     gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times Roman")))

 myplot2 <- arrangeGrob(myplot2, main = textGrob("B", x = unit(0, "npc")
     , y = unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
     gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times Roman")))

 myplot3 <- arrangeGrob(myplot3, main = textGrob("C", x = unit(0, "npc")
    , y  = unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
    gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times Roman")))

 myplot4 <- arrangeGrob(myplot4, main = textGrob("D", x = unit(0, "npc")
    , y = unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
    gp=gpar(col="black",    fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times Roman")))

 grid.arrange(myplot1, myplot2, myplot3, myplot4)
```

and I got the following plot, which was fine:

[image]

but under the new R version 3.2.2 the image looks like this:

[image]

arrangeGrob opens for every textGrob a new image and I got eight images on one page instead of four. How can I fixed it that the plot looks like in the old version of R and gridExtra?

Comment: There has been a rewrite of gridExtra, that is not (fully) backward compatible - may be the issue. Have a look at the new wiki https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html . Try changing `main` to `top`

Comment: Thank very much, it works!!!

Comment: Great stuff, please feel free to write it up as an answer

Comment: When I tried to save the result as an object `g <-arrangeGrob(myplot1, myplot2, myplot3, myplot4)`  I ended up with a TableGrob that prints as text, and needed a `plot(g)` to view it.

Comment: Doh -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458051/store-arrangegrob-to-object-does-not-create-printable-object says you need `grid.draw(g)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Kev's comment:

> There has been a rewrite of gridExtra, that is not (fully) backward
>   compatible - may be the issue. Have a look at the new wiki
>   cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/… . Try changing
>   main to top – user20650