# Overlay two differently formatted qplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, correspondence-analysis

I have two scatterplots, based on different but related data, created using qplot() from ggplot2. (Learning `ggplot` hasn't been a priority because `qplot` has been sufficient for my needs up to now). What I want to do is superimpose/overlay the two charts so that the x,y data for each is plotted in the same plot space. The complication is that I want each plot to retain its formatting/aesthetics.

That data in question are row and column scores from correspondence analysis - `corresp()` from `MASS` - so the number of data rows (i.e. samples or taxa) differ between the two datasets. I can plot the two score sets together easily. Either by combing the two datasets or, even easier, just using the `biplot()` function.

However, I have been using qplot to get the plots looking exactly as I need them; with samples plotted as colour-coded symbols and taxa as labels:

```
PlotSample <- qplot(DataCorresp$rscore[,1], DataCorresp$rscore[,2], 
                    colour=factor(DataAll$ColourCode)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black","darkgoldenrod2",
                                 "deepskyblue2","deeppink2"))
```

and

```
PlotTaxa <- qplot(DataCorresp$cscore[,1], DataCorresp$cscore[,2], 
                  label=colnames(DataCorresp), size=10, geom=“text”)
```

Can anyone suggest a way by which either

- the two plots (`PlotSample` and `PlotTaxa`) can be superimposed atop of each other,
- the two datasets (`DataCorresp$rscore` and `DataCorresp$cscore`) can be plotted together but formatted in their different ways, or
- another function (e.g. `biplot()`) that could be used to achieve my aim.

Example of workflow using a extremely simplified and made-up dataset:

```
> require(MASS)
> require(ggplot2)
> alldata<-read.csv("Fake data.csv",header=T,row.name=1)
> selectdata<-alldata[,2:10]
> alldata
          Period Species.1 Species.2 Species.3 Species.4 Species.5 Species.6
Sample-1   Early        50        87        97        12        60        49
Sample-2   Early        41        90        36        52        36        27
Sample-3   Early        87        56        82        45        56        13
Sample-4   Early        37        47        78        29        53        34
Sample-5   Early        58        70        34        35         8        21
Sample-6   Early        94        82        48        16        27        26
Sample-7   Early        91        69        50        57        24        13
Sample-8   Early        63        38        86        20        28        11
Sample-9  Middle         4        19        55        99        86        38
Sample-10 Middle        29        25        10        93        37        54
Sample-11 Middle        48        12        59        73        39        92
Sample-12 Middle        31         6        34        81        39        54
Sample-13 Middle        29        40        26        52        34        84
Sample-14 Middle         1        46        15        97        67        41
Sample-15   Late        43        47        30        18        60        23
Sample-16   Late        45        10        49         2         2        45
Sample-17   Late        14         8        51        36        58        51
Sample-18   Late        41        51        32        47        23        43
Sample-19   Late        43        17         6        54         4        12
Sample-20   Late        20        25         1        29        35         2
          Species.7 Species.8 Species.9
Sample-1         41        39        57
Sample-2         59         4        45
Sample-3         10        56         5
Sample-4         59        30        39
Sample-5          9        29        57
Sample-6         29        24        35
Sample-7         22         4        42
Sample-8         31        19        40
Sample-9         17         7        57
Sample-10         6         9        29
Sample-11        34        20         0
Sample-12        56        41        59
Sample-13         6        31        13
Sample-14        25        12        28
Sample-15        60        75        84
Sample-16        32        69        34
Sample-17        48        53        56
Sample-18        80        86        46
Sample-19        50        70        82
Sample-20        57        84        70
> biplot(selectca,cex=c(0.6,0.6))
> selectca<-corresp(selectdata,nf=5)
> PlotSample <- qplot(selectca$rscore[,1], selectca$rscore[,2], colour=factor(alldata$Period) )
> PlotTaxa<-qplot(selectca$cscore[,1], selectca$cscore[,2], label=colnames(selectdata), size=10, geom="text")
```

The biplot will produce this plot: /r/10wk1a8/5

The PlotSample appears as such: /r/i29cba/5

The PlotTaxa appears as such: /r/245bl9d/5

EDIT so don't have enough rep to post pictures and tinypic links not accepted (despite https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60563/how-to-upload-images-on-stack-overflow). So if you add tinypic's URL to the start of those codes above you'll get there.

Essentially I want to creat the biplot plot but with samples colour coded as they are in PlotSample.

Comment: Please [provide data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) for testing.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6620375/707145) helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Gavin Simpsons [ggvegan-package](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan)!

```
require(vegan)
require(ggvegan)
# some data
data(dune)

# CA
mod <- cca(dune)

# plot
autoplot(mod, geom = 'text')
```

[image]

For a finer control (or if you want to stick with `corresp()`, you may also want to take a look at the code of the two involved functions [fortify.cca](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan/blob/master/R/fortify.cca.R) (which wraps the data in the cca objects into a useable format for ggplot) and [autoplot.cca](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan/blob/master/R/autoplot.cca.R) for creating the plot.

I you want to do it from scratch, you'll have to wrap both scores (sites and species) into **one** data.frame (see how `fortify.cca` does this and extract the relevant values from the `corresp()` object) and use this to build  the plot.

Comment: How would I go about coding the samples/sites in this plot, e.g. using 'colours' in my original sample plot?